# Mocking a non class method in phpunit

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I've run into a situation with PHPUnit. I have a class that includes a php file that contains non class methods. In my class I have a method that calls the that function. Below is an example of my setup.

```
class foo
{
    public function getInfo() 
    {
        ....
        $this->GetFunctions();
        $data = functionFromRequire();
        ....
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return require_once '/PATH/TO/FILE/functions.php';
    }

}
```

PHPUnit getMock only mocks class functions. Is there anyway to mock non class functions with PHPUnit? Google results only seem to take me to mocking class functions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mock getInfo() instead? Or do something to avoid the getFunctions() method in that particular guise.

Comment: @markdwhite getInfo is the method I'm trying to unit test. I mock the call to getFunctions so it just returns true. Which causes the test to fail due to the function not existing.

Comment: I mean to mock getInfo() so it returns a suitable value as if $data had been supplied by functionFromRequire(). Alternatively, refactor to avoid getFunctions() entirely as surely that could be done in a more testable way.

Answer (score 1):

In short, PHPUnit did not have functionality to mock namespaces that I could find. I did some refactoring as @markdwhite suggested. I created a new class that included the old file. Then used the magic __call() and call_user_func_array() php functions in the newly created class. Since there was too many namespace functions to manually redo. Hope it helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Using namespacing, you can replace your function `functionFromRequire` for your `getInfo` test.  However, requiring the file explicitly as you do in your question will make this difficult.

http://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2011/03/php-mocking-built-in-functions-like-time-in-unit-tests/

You can wrap your test in and class in the same namespace and then replace the `functionFromRequire` with your own that will return a set value.  As long as you do not specify the namespace of the function, you can replace it and PHP will be able to handle it properly.